# Execute grep and kill pid in single line in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, grep, kill

I need to execute the grep pid and kill -9 command in the same line in shell script as to pass it in expect command but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Is all that supposed to be happening on the remote host? That command substitution will be executed on your local machine before the shell invokes ssh. You need a form like `ssh use@remote bash -c 'stuff to execute remotely'`. If you're using expect, you'll need to use braces instead of single quotes. But `pkill` is definitely easier.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes. I need the grep and kill steps to be executed on a remote host.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pkill PATTERN`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill):

```
pkill 'jvm'
```

> pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout.

Comment: The pkill is not working for me. I am able to see the pid even after executing pkill

Comment: Try `pill -9 jvm`

Comment: I don't seem to have sudo access to execute pkill; Is there a way where I can proceed with kill?

Comment: @clueless Most likely, no.